# Altair setting constant label color for bar chart

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

An example of setting labels for a bar chart in Altair is provided in official website here: https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/bar_chart_with_labels.html

However, once you want to set the "color" parameter in the bar chart conditioned to a variable, the label colours automatically match the color of the bar which is illustrated below. However, my intention is to have constant label color, like black all the time. This is especially desirable for stacked bar charts if you want to show the label as percentage. It seems like setting "color='black'" in the mark_text does not work here; probably because it is based on "bars" which uses "color" parameter as "year". But I could not find an intuitive way to decouple this parameter.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.wheat()

bars = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='wheat:Q',
    y="year:O",
    color='year:O'

)

text = bars.mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
        color='black',
    dx=3  # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
).encode(
    text='wheat:Q'

)

(bars + text).properties(height=900)
```

[Bar chart with Variable Label Colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNSZj.png)

[Stacked Bar Chart Example with coloured labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohv7x.png)

Comment: Hello, I am not sure if I understand what you want correctly : the whole point of setting an encoding color is to map the variable to a color, which will be different for all the levels of your variable. If you want a constant color, just drop the `color=... ` in the encoding. Is that what you want or am I missing something?

Comment: I added a stacked bar chart example to illustrate the problem. I would like to use "color" encoding in the stacked bar chart to illustrate different components that ends up to 100%. In this scheme, visually it is preferable to have single Label color like black rather than different colors that might blend and lost in the stacked bar chart.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a stacked bar chart with all the colors the same? Something [like that](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/normalized_stacked_bar_chart.html) but with all the colors the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `bars.mark_text()` the resulting chart inherits everything you specified within the bars chart, including the color encoding. To avoid having a color encoding for the text, the best approach is to make sure it doesn't inherit a color encoding.

For example:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.wheat()

base = alt.Chart(source).encode(
    x='wheat:Q',
    y="year:O"
)

bars = base.mark_bar().encode(
    color='year:O'
)

text = base.mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=3  # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
).encode(
    text='wheat:Q'
)

(bars + text).properties(height=900)
```

The reason `mark_text(color='black')` didn't override the encoding in your snippet is because the color encoding takes precedence over mark properties, as described in [Global Config vs. Local Config vs. Encoding](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#global-config-vs-local-config-vs-encoding).

Comment: Hi Jake, 
If I need to keep colors in the alt.Chart specification (for legends) - is there still any workaround available to have black mark_text

Comment: I believe the code in the answer above does what you want.