# Altair: Setting Raw Color Values Messes Up SortField

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, altair

I'm trying to create an Altair barplot with the bars sorted by 'count' and then apply [raw color values](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html) to the bars.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

# Dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': ['apple', 'orange', 'blueberry', 'pear', 'grape', 'kiwi', 'strawberry', 'lychee'],
                  'count': [2, 4, 1, 7, 9, 12, 16, 35], 
                  'label': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
                  'colors': ['#4c78a8', '#f58518', '#e45756', '#72b7b2', '#54a24b', '#eeca3b', '#b279a2', 
                             '#9d755d']})

def make_alt_chart(df):
    g = alt.Chart(df).encode(
        x=alt.X('count'), 
        y=alt.Y('fruit', sort=alt.SortField(field='count', order='descending'))
    ).properties(
        width=700,
        height=650,
    )
    
    bars = g.mark_bar(
        size=60,
    ).encode(
        color=alt.Color('colors', sort=alt.SortField('count', order='descending'),
                        scale=None, legend=None)
    ).properties(height=alt.Step(75))

    text = g.mark_text(
        align='center',
        baseline='middle',
        dx=28
    ).encode(
        text='label'
    ).interactive()
    
    return (bars + text)

fruits = make_alt_chart(df)

fruits
```

Adding `sort=alt.SortField(field='count', order='descending')` to y= gets the chart sorted how I want, but when I add `color=alt.Color('colors', sort=alt.SortField('count', order='descending'), scale=None, legend=None)` to bars, the order on the y axis is no longer sorted by 'count'.

This is what the fruits chart looks like after running the above code:
[image: Fruits chart]

This is what my desired output would look like, but with the custom colors applied:
[image: Sorted fruits chart without colors applied]

If there's an easier way to set custom colors in Altair please let me know.

Note: The color hex values are the tableau10 scheme but dropping the pink shade.

I've reviewed these resources but haven't been able to figure it out:

- [altair.Color Documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Color.html)
- [Altair Customizing Visualizations Docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html)
- [Vega Color Schemes Docs](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/)
- [Altair issues: sort not working on alt.Y](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/643)
- [SO: Setting constant label color for bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54015250/altair-setting-constant-label-color-for-bar-chart)
- [SO: Sorting based on alt.Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60626992/sorting-based-on-the-alt-color-field-in-altair)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in the Javascript console, you see that the renderer is outputting this warning:

```
WARN Domains that should be unioned has conflicting sort properties. Sort will be set to true.
```

The relevant [Vega-Lite issue](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/2038) suggests the workaround; replace

```
y=alt.Y('fruit', sort=alt.SortField(field='count', order='descending'))
```

with

```
y=alt.Y('fruit', sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field='count', order='descending', op='sum'))
```

This is the result:
[image]